# How to define a strong IBOutlet property in Swift?

Tags: ios, macos, swift

According to [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WritingSwiftClassesWithObjective-CBehavior.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH5-XID_57), the compiler replaces `@IBOutlet var name: Type` with `@IBOutlet weak var name: Type! = nil`. Then how to define a strong IBOutlet property? `@IBOutlet strong var name: Type` gives a compiler error.

Comment: Are you using Beta 3 (which was released just yesterday)?  The latest beta should support strong IBOutlets.

Comment: Ahh..no. I am still using Beta 2. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had to set the type optional: 
`@IBOutlet strong var textView: UITextView? = nil`

and then call it:

```
self.textView!.text = "Jeps"
```

Outlets to `AnyObject` are not possible in beta 3

Answer (score 0):

As of Xcode 6 beta 3, Swift now allows marking `@IBOutlets` as `strong`.

From the [release notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_6_beta_3_lpw27r/xcode_6_beta_3_release_notes_.pdf):

> • @IBOutlets may be explicitly marked strong to override their
>   implicitly-weak behavior. (16954464)